# Symfony 4.4 getResult hydrator slow - PHP 8.1

Tags: mysql, performance, doctrine, php-8.1, symfony-4.4

I updated my old Symfony 4.3 application to 4.4 and i moved the application on a new server with PHP8.1 and mySQL8. Before i used a Server with PHP7.4.

I noticed now that my application is very slow on the new setup.
Some routes are 1 second slower other 4-5 seconds.And a very big command which takes 7 minutes to execute on the old system, takes now multiple hours.

My code is defenetly not perfect but such an increase cant be normal.

For example, i found this simple database request:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select("k")
        ->from(KVP::class, "k")
        ->andWhere("k.deleted = false")
        ->andWhere("(k.accept = 1 or k.deniedFrom is NOT NULL) and (k.done is NOT NULL or k.until is NULL)")
        ->addOrderBy('k.createdAt', 'DESC');
$queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

When i change getResult to getArrayResult, the route loads 500ms faster. On the old setup, there is no differnce in execution time between getResult and getArrayResult.

Do i need to make some specific configurations for PHP8 or do i need to change the code?

Here is an excerpt of the KVP entity from the example:

```
 namespace App\Entity\KVP;

     use App\Annotation\Acl;
     use App\Entity\Auth\User;
     use App\Entity\Employee\Department;
     use App\Traits\TableExtensionTrait;
     use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
     use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
     use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * KVP entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\KVP\KVPRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="t_kvp")
 *
 *
 * @Gedmo\Loggable
 * @Acl
 */
class KVP
{
    // Includes create/update information
    use TableExtensionTrait;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\ToDos\ToDos", mappedBy="kvp")
     */
    protected $todos;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\News\News", mappedBy="kvp")
     */
    protected $newsKVP;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Chat\ChatGroup")
     */
    private $chatGroup;

    /**
     * @var User
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Auth\User", inversedBy="kvp")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var User
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Auth\User", inversedBy="kvpResponsible")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userResponsible_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userResponsible;

    /**
     * @var Department
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Employee\Department", inversedBy="kvpDepartment")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="department_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $department;

    /**
     * @var User
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Auth\User", inversedBy="kvpAcceptedFrom")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="acceptedFrom_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $acceptedFrom;

    /**
     * @var User
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Auth\User", inversedBy="kvpDeniedFrom")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="deniedFrom_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deniedFrom;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="text", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="field.not.blank")
     */
    private $title;
```

And here is my composer.json:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "beberlei/doctrineextensions": "^1.2",
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4.2",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.13",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.7.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.13",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.2",
        "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "^3.9",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^5.0",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "^1.7",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.3.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.3",
        "symfony/asset": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/console": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/intl": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/process": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/translation": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/validator": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.7",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.4.*",
        "twig/extensions": "^1.5",
        "umulmrum/holiday": "^0.6.0",
        "michaeldegroot/doctrine-encrypt-bundle": "5.1.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.2",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.4.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "symfony/flex": true
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.4.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Does someone had the same experience or an idea what i am missing here?

**EDIT**

I think i could narrow it down to doctrine hydration. When i i make getResult with enitites that has multiple connection to other entities then i get the performance problem. On the old setup/version
is everything fine.

This is the SQL from the request above as requested:

```
SELECT t0_.id AS id_0, t0_.title AS title_1, t0_.problemState AS problemState_2, t0_.solution AS solution_3, t0_.accept AS accept_4, t0_.until AS until_5, t0_.inWork AS inWork_6, t0_.accepted AS accepted_7, t0_.comment AS comment_8, t0_.commentInWork AS commentInWork_9, t0_.deleted AS deleted_10, t0_.greenKvp AS greenKvp_11, t0_.done AS done_12, t0_.reminderSupervised AS reminderSupervised_13, t0_.lastReminderSupervised AS lastReminderSupervised_14, t0_.reminderAdmins AS reminderAdmins_15, t0_.lastReminderAdmins AS lastReminderAdmins_16, t0_.reminderSuperAdmins AS reminderSuperAdmins_17, t0_.lastReminderSuperAdmins AS lastReminderSuperAdmins_18, t0_.reminderOpen AS reminderOpen_19, t0_.lastReminderOpen AS lastReminderOpen_20, t0_.created_at AS created_at_21, t0_.updated_at AS updated_at_22, t0_.update_version AS update_version_23, t0_.chat_group_id AS chat_group_id_24, t0_.user_id AS user_id_25, t0_.userResponsible_id AS userResponsible_id_26, t0_.department_id AS department_id_27, t0_.acceptedFrom_id AS acceptedFrom_id_28, t0_.deniedFrom_id AS deniedFrom_id_29, t0_.created_by AS created_by_30, t0_.updated_by AS updated_by_31 
FROM t_kvp t0_ 
WHERE t0_.deleted = 0 
ORDER BY t0_.created_at DESC
```

And the SHOW CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_kvp` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `chat_group_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `department_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `problemState` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `solution` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `accept` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `until` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `inWork` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `accepted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `commentInWork` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `greenKvp` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `done` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `reminderSupervised` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastReminderSupervised` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `reminderAdmins` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastReminderAdmins` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `reminderSuperAdmins` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastReminderSuperAdmins` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `reminderOpen` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastReminderOpen` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_version` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `userResponsible_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `acceptedFrom_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `deniedFrom_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_34FC256BCA760E77` (`chat_group_id`),
  KEY `IDX_34FC256BA76ED395` (`user_id`),
  KEY `IDX_34FC256BEC9046B3` (`userResponsible_id`),
  KEY `IDX_34FC256BAE80F5DF` (`department_id`),
  KEY `IDX_34FC256BB6A8B8C4` (`acceptedFrom_id`),
  KEY `IDX_34FC256B36D52A95` (`deniedFrom_id`),
  KEY `IDX_34FC256BDE12AB56` (`created_by`),
  KEY `IDX_34FC256B16FE72E1` (`updated_by`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_34FC256B16FE72E1` FOREIGN KEY (`updated_by`) REFERENCES `t_user` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_34FC256B36D52A95` FOREIGN KEY (`deniedFrom_id`) REFERENCES `t_user` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_34FC256BA76ED395` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `t_user` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_34FC256BAE80F5DF` FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) REFERENCES `t_department` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_34FC256BB6A8B8C4` FOREIGN KEY (`acceptedFrom_id`) REFERENCES `t_user` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_34FC256BCA760E77` FOREIGN KEY (`chat_group_id`) REFERENCES `t_chat_group` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_34FC256BDE12AB56` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `t_user` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_34FC256BEC9046B3` FOREIGN KEY (`userResponsible_id`) REFERENCES `t_user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=228 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

When i select only a few fields with no connection to other entities then the server response is fine.

This is only an example. The problem is every where where i grap data that has connections to multiple entities. (Sorry for the bad explanation :) )

**EDIT 2**

I have looked at the Symfony performance results on both setups and there it seems the problem is not Doctrine/Database. I seams is PHP after all, or did i interpret the screenshots wrong?

*Symfony 4.4 PHP 8.1*
[image]

*Symfony 4.3 PHP 7.4*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    ->andWhere("k.deleted = false")
    ->andWhere("(k.accept = 1 or k.deniedFrom is NOT NULL) and (k.done is NOT NULL or k.until is NULL)")
```

That messy `WHERE` smells like something that you tack onto every `SELECT`.  Correct?  Boil it down to a single flag, maybe `is_valid`.  (Keep the details, too, if you need them.)  We *cannot* optimize that stuff.

Show us the generated SQL and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  With those, we can help with performance.

**More**

It looks like the whole table will be scanned.  How big is the table?  Are many of the rows "deleted"?